# Microsoft Forms attachment error: "not enough storage space"

Tags: microsoft-forms

I have a form that's been working without issue for months now.  And suddenly users are getting the following error.

[image]

The form is connected to a M365 group, so all attachments are saved to their doc library and the site settings show only 2G used out of 100G.  I've tried searching but "MS Forms" is terrible for googling.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with one of my form as well. When I check the Sharepoint folder associated with the form, there is very little in it as I have a MS flow that takes the uploaded files and move them in a different M365 group based on the information entered in the fields. There are only a handful of web pages on that Sharepoint and it's not used to store any other files.

This form is only used a few times every month as well with around 0-3 file uploads per use, so it's not like gigabytes of data is being uploaded frequently either.

Here is a screenshot of the Sharepoint storage where the form is stored. Less than 100 mb is used total.

[image]

Comment: I have found the answer to my problem. The structure of a forms file upload folder is as such in a M365 group:

Documents > Applications > Microsoft Forms > (Form name) > (One folder per question that asks to upload file)

For some reason, the last folder (question) was gone and recreating it wasn't working. I did the following steps:

1. Rename my current forms
2. Copied the forms
3. Renamed the new forms to the proper name
4. Renamed the (forms name) folder in the M365 group
5. Updated the link to the forms in the Teams tab
6. Tested my MS flow

This worked for me.